# Preserving order of messages- executor service java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Suppose we have a process that receives a set of events. For each of the events, we call an executor service to process incoming events in another thread. I would like to know if the order of events will be preserved or not? If it affects order of events, how can I preserve the order of events without using queues.

```
public void process(PacketContext context) {

      if (context == null) {
        log.error("Packet context is null");
        return;
      }

      PacketContextProtoOuterClass.PacketContextProto packetContextProto =
          PacketContextProtoTranslator.translate(context);

      for (String clientId : clientList) {
        String key = clientId + ServicesProto.topicType.PACKET_CONTEXT.toString();
        Notification notification =
            Notification.newBuilder()
                .setClientId(clientId)
                .setPacketContext(packetContextProto)
                .build();
        if (observerMap.containsKey(key)) {
          Runnable runnable =
              () -> {
                observerMap.get(key).onNext(notification);
              };

          executorService.execute(runnable);
}
```

Comment: order is not preserved, and if you have dependency then why do need to use executorservice?

Comment: I am using grpc streaming and it looks like when I call onNext inside of my current thread  to send event to a client, it conflicts with the current thread and terminates the connection. But when I execute onNext in a separate thread then it works fine.

Comment: `terminates the connection` because of time out? can you share the code and problem

Comment: I shared the code and it looks like the order is persevered. If I omit the execute part and call onNext directly, I will get this error: grpc.statusruntimeexception: cancelled: call already cancelled

Comment: In the above code, I use a hashMap for the client observers since my process should be outside of onNext function.